# SQL Server Find record between two dates

Tags: sql

Let me explain I have an list of employees that say when they actually worked.  I have another table that gives me period and begin and Ending Dates for that period.  I want a query that will take the day worked and finds the period that it falls in.

```
table 1

David  05/10/2013
Peter  05/16/2013

table 2
Period_Num         Begin_Period         End_Period
Period 1            01/05/2013        05/15/2013
Period 2            05/16/2013        12/31/2013
```

I want the final to read:

```
David      Period 1
Peter      Period 2
```

Is there a way to do this in `sql` particularly in a view?

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest I am a little lost on whether I need to use a sub query or a function or case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
select t1.Name, t2.Period_Num
from table1 as t1
    left outer join table2 as t2 on t1.date between t2.Begin_Period and T2.End_Period
```

you should be careful, because if periods in table2 are overlapping, your records could duplicate. For example, if your data is:

```
table 1

David  05/10/2013
Peter  05/16/2013

table 2
Period_Num         Begin_Period         End_Period
Period 1             01/05/2013         05/15/2013
Period 2             05/16/2013         12/31/2013
Period 3             03/08/2013         08/10/2013
```

you'll receive

```
David      Period 1
Peter      Period 2
David      Period 3 <- DUPLICATE
```

Comment: I understand and this was much easier than I was making it.  Thanks.  I have FK constraints on table 2..Your caution will not happen.  Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`select Table1.Name,Table2.periodNum from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.period between Table2.Begin_Period   and Table2.End_Period`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid missing name from table1 in case there is no corresponding period in table2, you can try something like this :

```
select t1.Name, isnull(t2.Period_Num,'n/a')
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.worked between t2.Begin_Period and t2.End_Period
```